# Get Arbitrary Slices of Bits from Bytestring

Tags: haskell, binary, bit, bytestring, bitstream

I want to use a lazy `Bytestring` to represent a stream of bits. I need to be able to take arbitrary slices of bits from this stream efficiently. For example, I might have a `ByteString` of length 10, and I'd like slice a new `ByteString` consisting of bits 24-36 from the original `ByteString`.

The problem is that `ByteStrings` are arrays of `Word8`s, so taking ranges that are not multiples of 8 is difficult. The best I've been able to come up with is this, using `Data.Binary` and `Data.Binary.Bits`. Note that `get32BitRange` is specifically for ranges <= 32.

```
get32BitRange :: Int -> Int -> ByteString -> ByteString
get32BitRange lo hi = runPut . putWord32be
                    . runGet (runBitGet . block $ word8 (8 - (lo `quot` 8)) *> word32be len)
                    . drop offset
    where len = hi - lo
          lo' = lo `div` 8
          offset = fromIntegral lo' - 1
```

The algorithm is:

- find the index of the first `Word8` containing the bits I want
- drop from the `ByteString` up to that index
- if the low end of the bit range is not a multiple of 8, there will be some excess bits at the beginning of the `Word8`, so skip those
- get (hi - lo) bits, and store in a `Word32`
- put that `Word32` into a `ByteString`

It looks more than a little ugly, is there a more efficient way to grab arbitrary slices of bits from a `ByteString`?

EDIT: here is a more efficient version

```
get32BitRange :: Int -> Int -> ByteString -> Word32
get32BitRange lo hi = runGet get
    where get = runBitGet . block $ byteString byteOff *> word8 bitOff *> word32be len
          len = hi - lo
          (byteOff, bitOff) = lo `quotRem` 8
```

Comment: Did you know that plain, boring old `UArray` already uses a very tight packed representation if it contains `Bool`? Why not use that?

Comment: @DanielWagner: I had not thought of that, and that would be an elegant solution to my problem, but unfortunately I need to use lazy `ByteString`s and I dont think I'd be able to keep the laziness while converting to a `UAarray` or unboxed `Vector`. I could try a boxed representation though, and see how it fairs, but efficiency is key here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to mark this as resolved. This is what I ended up using:

```
get32BitRange :: Int -> Int -> ByteString -> Word32
get32BitRange lo hi = assert (lo < hi) $
    runGet (runBitGet bitGet)
    where bitGet = block $ byteString byteOff
                         *> word8 bitOff
                         *> word32be len
          len = hi - lo
          (byteOff, bitOff) = lo `quotRem` 8
```

Answer (score 2):

I think other solutions are way better *but* you can use the Internal module to get at the underlying structure: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.10.2.0/doc/html/src/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#ByteString

```
data ByteString = PS {-# UNPACK #-} !(ForeignPtr Word8) -- payload
                     {-# UNPACK #-} !Int                -- offset
                     {-# UNPACK #-} !Int                -- length
```

Then you can use standard pointer tools to generate `ByteString`s pointing exactly where you want, by manipulating the `ForeignPtr` directly...

Answer (score 1):

You can't make this efficient with `ByteString` as your API type, because it doesn't carry the information that the "bits" you want really start at some offset into the first byte.

Best bet is to make a wrapper type:

```
data BitStream =
    BitStream {
        info :: ByteString,
        -- values from 0-7: ignore all bits in the first byte up to
        -- but not including this offset
        firstBitOffset :: !Int,to but not including this offset
        -- values from 0-7: ignore all bits in the last byte after
        -- but not including this offset
        lastBitOffset :: !Int
    }
```

Then you can design a bit-based API around this.

Comment: this would certainly help clean up my example function, but I'm more interested in a method to actually extract the slices of bits.

Comment: what do you want to do with them afterwards?

Comment: parse them as binary data, probably to a `Word` or `Int` type